# How can we use prepush and event.cancel?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I couldnt find example of using prepush and event.cancel function.

http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#event-prepush

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event handler to the `prepush` event. The event object will have a method called `event.cancel()`. If you call that method the push will be cancelled.

```
navi.on('prepush', function(event) {
  var cancel = window.confirm('Do you want to cancel?');
  if (cancel) {
    event.cancel();
  }
});
```

Please check out this pen for a working example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/oXvgZz